# Flutter: How to create and expose a picture to the public download folder?

Tags: flutter, dart

Working on a Flutter app that supposes to creates images on the public Downloads folder. It works fine on the device. But the problem is images don't exists once you try to access them through a Pc connection. Please help.

Here is the code Im using:

```
final picker = ImagePicker();

      picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera).then((pickedFile) {
        var myImagePath = path;//suppose to be /storage/emulated/0/Download/SomeFolder
        var imageName = ...;
        new File("$myImagePath/$imageName.jpg").writeAsBytesSync(File(pickedFile.path).readAsBytesSync());
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what do you mean by PC connection in your case? Are you trying to take an image from your phone and upload to the PC?

Comment: Im trying to access the images I create through the app. The images should be on a folder like :'This PC\Lenovo Tab E10\SanDisk SD card\Download\00abc123'